# asterisk incoming/miss call notification (to skype)

Tags: asterisk

My environment: **Centos 5.6**, **Asterisk with freepbx** , **skype** i.e.sends message with parameter skype.sh skype_user message.

Now i wanted to send skype notification so that my asterisk server notification
are sent to skype rather than email (or to both skype and email).

I know, there is `voicemail.conf`, `voicemail_general` and `vm_email.inc,` which has these body created.

```
vm_email.inc

emailbody=${VM_NAME},\n\nThere is a new voicemail in mailbox ${VM_MAILBOX}
```

But i dont see where is something like "mail" command.

What my thought to do is: instead of saying "mailcmd" pass
system ( `/path/to/script`) and it would simply send message as rest is already configured.

Any suggestion where i could run script rather than sending email
Or Executing script on every incoming call, so that i could send as notification on every call over the Skype. **(however, ultimate goal is to achieve miss call notification or voice mail notification over Skype.)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found solution,

It was fairly simple while trying to run script.. with `system(/path/to/script)..`

previously it didn't work due to the conflicts among the context while trying to intercept freepbx routing with manual routing.

```
[notification]
exten=> _.,1,NoOp(Incoming Call)
exten=> _.,n,System(/etc/asterisk/skype.sh CS 'Call From ${CALLERID(all)}')
```

As it would send notification on every Inbound hosted from same provider (or atleast with same context)

I wrote more to skip if its not certain DDI number.

```
[notification]
exten=> _.,1,NoOp(Incoming Call)
exten=> _.,n,GotoIf($["${CALLERID(dnid)}" != "44xxxxxxxxxx"]?final)
exten=> _.,n,System(/etc/asterisk/skype.sh CS 'Call From ${CALLERID(all)}')
exten=> _.,n,NoOp(Sending to PSTN Now)
exten=> _.,n,goto(from-pstn,${EXTEN},1)
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.theschmandts.org/blog/email-notifications-for-missed-calls-in-asterisk

This might be helpful..

Comment: i read through, and i will go again, but wont be easy to implement with existing queue or inbound.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! While your answer may be helpful [we generally like to see answers with enough content to stand on their own if the sites they link to go away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  Please consider updating your answer to include enough information to still be helpful if the link breaks.